# GDB error raised: "no executable file specified"

Tags: python, gdb, gdb-python

I am trying to use `gdb` to debug a program that includes a module written in C++. I downloaded the latest version of `gdb` using homebrew.

I tried to run the following command:

```
(gdb) run Pyrh_test.py
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Starting program:  Pyrh_test.py
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
```

Then I tried using the "file" and "exec-file" commands like the following (outputs also included):

```
(gdb) file Pyrh_test.py
"/Users/danielribeiro/opt/Python/Spyder/Pyrh_test.py": not in executable format: file format not recognized
(gdb) exec-file Pyrh_test.py
"/Users/danielribeiro/opt/Python/Spyder/Pyrh_test.py": not in executable format: file format not recognized
```

How can I use `gdb` to run `Pyrh_test.py`?

Answer (score 1):

What the OP has almost works for me - just needs one tweak which is adding python to the beginning gdb command:

```
1. $ gdb python3
```

Then the **run** command works

```
2. (gdb) run py.py 
Starting program: /usr/bin/python3 py.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
main started
[ ... ]
```

You can also test if gdb is running python by invoking directly instead of attempting to run a .py file:

```
$ gdb python3
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.0.90-0ubuntu1) 12.0.90
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[ ... ]

(gdb) run
>>> print("This is the python prompt.")
This is the python prompt.
```

### System specs

And for reference:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.0.90-0ubuntu1) 12.0.90
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.6
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use gdb to run Pyrh_test.py?

You don't *run* `Pyrh_test.py`. You run `Python`, which *interprets* the `.py` file.

The way to debug this is to run `Python` under GDB, like so:

```
gdb --args python Pyrh_test.py
(gdb) run
```